# The type or namespace name 'ICloudRecoEventHandler' could not be found

Tags: c#, vuforia, vuforia-cloud-recognition

**EDITED**

> I changed my Unity version to `2018.3.8f1` and Vuforia version to `8.0.10` and it worked. But anyone knows how to work in the newest version?

I am following [this tutorial](https://library.vuforia.com/content/vuforia-library/en/articles/Solution/How-To-Implement-Cloud-Reco.html) to implement Cloud Reco in Unity.

Error in my `SimpleCloudHandler.cs` script:

> error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'ICloudRecoEventHandler' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

My Unity version is `2018.3.14f1`
My Vuforia version is `8.1.7`

My code following the tutorial:

```
using Vuforia;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class SimpleCloudHandler : MonoBehaviour, ICloudRecoEventHandler 
{
    private CloudRecoBehaviour mCloudRecoBehaviour;
    private bool mIsScanning = false;
    private string mTargetMetadata = "";
    public ImageTargetBehaviour ImageTargetTemplate;

    public void OnInitialized(TargetFinder targetFinder) {
        Debug.Log ("Cloud Reco initialized");
    }

    public void OnInitError(TargetFinder.InitState initError) {
        Debug.Log ("Cloud Reco init error " + initError.ToString());
    }

    public void OnUpdateError(TargetFinder.UpdateState updateError) {
        Debug.Log ("Cloud Reco update error " + updateError.ToString());
    }

    public void OnStateChanged(bool scanning) {
        mIsScanning = scanning;
        if (scanning)
        {
            // clear all known trackables
            var tracker = TrackerManager.Instance.GetTracker<ObjectTracker>();
            tracker.TargetFinder.ClearTrackables(false);
        }
    }

    // Here we handle a cloud target recognition event
    public void OnNewSearchResult(TargetFinder.TargetSearchResult targetSearchResult) {
        TargetFinder.CloudRecoSearchResult cloudRecoSearchResult = 
            (TargetFinder.CloudRecoSearchResult)targetSearchResult;
        // do something with the target metadata
        mTargetMetadata = cloudRecoSearchResult.MetaData;
        // stop the target finder (i.e. stop scanning the cloud)
        mCloudRecoBehaviour.CloudRecoEnabled = false;

        // Build augmentation based on target
        if (ImageTargetTemplate) {
            // enable the new result with the same ImageTargetBehaviour:
            ObjectTracker tracker = TrackerManager.Instance.GetTracker<ObjectTracker>();
            ImageTargetBehaviour imageTargetBehaviour =
                (ImageTargetBehaviour)tracker.TargetFinder.EnableTracking(
            targetSearchResult, ImageTargetTemplate.gameObject);
        }
    }

    void OnGUI() {
        // Display current 'scanning' status
        GUI.Box (new Rect(100,100,200,50), mIsScanning ? "Scanning" : "Not scanning");
        // Display metadata of latest detected cloud-target
        GUI.Box (new Rect(100,200,200,50), "Metadata: " + mTargetMetadata);
        // If not scanning, show button
        // so that user can restart cloud scanning
        if (!mIsScanning) {
            if (GUI.Button(new Rect(100,300,200,50), "Restart Scanning")) {
            // Restart TargetFinder
            mCloudRecoBehaviour.CloudRecoEnabled = true;
            }
        }
    }

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        mCloudRecoBehaviour = GetComponent<CloudRecoBehaviour>();

        if (mCloudRecoBehaviour){
            mCloudRecoBehaviour.RegisterEventHandler(this);
        }
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem on Unity 2019.1.12f1. The problem is that the tutorial is out of date. See e.g. [this site](https://developer.vuforia.com/forum/cloud-recognition/icloudrecoeventhandler-missing) saying that `ICloudRecoEventHandler` was renamed into `IObjectRecoEventHandler` and [this post](https://developer.vuforia.com/forum/cloud-recognition/getting-started-unityvuforia-cloud-reco), where the two Vuforia samples BASE and BOOKS are recommended to use.

I have worked through this recently and found that the following script works as `SimpleCloudHandler.cs`.

If you like, get in touch and we help each other on the way!

```
using UnityEngine;
using Vuforia;
public class SimpleCloudHandler : MonoBehaviour, IObjectRecoEventHandler
{
    private CloudRecoBehaviour mCloudRecoBehaviour;
    private bool mIsScanning = false;
    private string mTargetMetadata = "";
    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {
        // register this event handler at the cloud reco behaviour
        mCloudRecoBehaviour = GetComponent<CloudRecoBehaviour>();

        if (mCloudRecoBehaviour)
        {
            mCloudRecoBehaviour.RegisterEventHandler(this);
        }
    }

    public void OnInitialized(TargetFinder targetFinder)
    {
        Debug.Log("Cloud Reco initialized");
    }
    public void OnInitError(TargetFinder.InitState initError)
    {
        Debug.Log("Cloud Reco init error " + initError.ToString());
    }
    public void OnUpdateError(TargetFinder.UpdateState updateError)
    {
        Debug.Log("Cloud Reco update error " + updateError.ToString());
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// when we start scanning, unregister Trackable from the ImageTargetBehaviour, 
    /// then delete all trackables
    /// This function is from CloudRecoEventHandler.cs from Vuforia Base sample
    /// </summary>
    public void OnStateChanged(bool scanning)
    {
        Debug.Log("<color=blue>OnStateChanged(): </color>" + scanning);

        // Changing CloudRecoBehaviour.CloudRecoEnabled to false will call:
        // 1. TargetFinder.Stop()
        // 2. All registered ICloudRecoEventHandler.OnStateChanged() with false.

        // Changing CloudRecoBehaviour.CloudRecoEnabled to true will call:
        // 1. TargetFinder.StartRecognition()
        // 2. All registered ICloudRecoEventHandler.OnStateChanged() with true.
    }


    // Here we handle a cloud target recognition event
    public void OnNewSearchResult(TargetFinder.TargetSearchResult targetSearchResult)
    {
        TargetFinder.CloudRecoSearchResult cloudRecoSearchResult =
            (TargetFinder.CloudRecoSearchResult)targetSearchResult;
        // do something with the target metadata
        mTargetMetadata = cloudRecoSearchResult.MetaData;
        // stop the target finder (i.e. stop scanning the cloud)
        mCloudRecoBehaviour.CloudRecoEnabled = false;
    }


    void OnGUI()
    {
        // Display current 'scanning' status
        GUI.Box(new Rect(100, 100, 200, 50), mIsScanning ? "Scanning" : "Not scanning");
        // Display metadata of latest detected cloud-target
        GUI.Box(new Rect(100, 200, 200, 50), "Metadata: " + mTargetMetadata);
        // If not scanning, show button
        // so that user can restart cloud scanning
        if (!mIsScanning)
        {
            if (GUI.Button(new Rect(100, 300, 200, 50), "Restart Scanning"))
            {
                // Restart TargetFinder
                mCloudRecoBehaviour.CloudRecoEnabled = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```